# I would like to have more than 30+10 votes per day

Tags: feature-request, voting, privileges, rate-limiting

I feel like I never have enough up- and down-votes per day.

As Stack Overflow continues to grow, we continue to see a larger influx of questions every day.  Some are great, some are decent, some are *meh*, and some are downright awful.

Most days, I run out of votes (both up and down) in a matter of a few hours, and that's including the bonus 10 votes on questions.

I'll freely admit -- I cast more downvotes than upvotes anymore, because I see ***so many bad questions***.  Maybe I'm just on here too much, maybe I'm overly-critical, maybe I'm jaded, or, as I am inclined to believe, there really are *that many more* bad questions on the site.  Maybe it's a combination of all three, who knows.

**Getting to my point**, I would like the ability to have more votes per day.  It doesn't have to be a lot, but 40 just doesn't feel like it's enough anymore.

For Delete votes, you get 5 Delete votes at 10K reputation, and then an extra vote per 1000 reputation.  Maybe we can do something along the lines of that?

- At 10K reputation you get an extra vote, and an extra vote per 1000 reputation after that (or 5000 reputation if we want to take baby steps)
- or, based on the number of successful moderation flags, you get a certain number of extra votes per day, because, hey, you're clearly good at community moderating.

I have 50 close votes per day (which get used up as well)... for the sake of completeness, if it's a really terrible day of questions, why can't I downvote each one I vote to close as well?

Comment: I never use up my votes. Is there a way to determine how many people are using all their votes? If you're the only person it's going to affect, then I don't think it's worth the effort <_<

Comment: Maybe you should be!  I'm sure if this request was considered, due diligence would be done to see how many people are in fact repeatedly hitting their daily vote limit.  I doubt I'm the *only* person on the entire site to run out of votes on a daily basis, but I guess we'll see.

Comment: I use most of my votes and close votes every weekday (not so much weekends).

Comment: A free up/down vote on any question you vote to close.

Comment: Some people don't use all their votes because they know there's a limit and they don't want to run out. Even if you look at how many people currently use all of their votes, it will only give you a lower bound on how many people would use more votes if you increased the limit.

Comment: One argument in favour of limiting the number of votes is to prevent a relatively small number of very active SO users become "dominating" in the site, or, perhaps better, we might reverse it and say it allows even moderately active users to have an influence.

Comment: Instead of asking for more votes, maybe you should run for moderator. Then you can just close all that crap with no limits. :)

Comment: @Mysticial - eh, I tried moderating the Board & Card Game beta site years ago.  Although I'm sure it's different moderating a fledgling site versus well-established site, I found full-blown Moderator-hood to be extremely challenging, and strangely, very isolating.  I doubt I could reign in my sarcasm enough for SO, either :)  Although it *would* be lovely to just close all those tool request questions...

Comment: do you use VLQ? it resolves into downvote (from a Community user) if a question gets closed while this flag is active

Comment: I think for these low-quality OPs closing their question is more effective than downvoting it: they just don't seem to care. But a closed question is a waste even of the little effort they put in it. So I'd rather have more closing powers than more votes, as in, a heavier weight for close votes cast by established users. Not necessarily as heavy as the dupe hammer, but maybe counting for two or three for specialist badges. It nags me that most of my close-votes hardly ever get enough company, while I think I've been around long enough to know when a question needs closing.

Comment: @gnat I think SE stopped applying automatic downvotes in such cases sometime this year. I may well be wrong, but do you have a reference describing this rule?

Comment: @Behaviour: the downvote is only applied once the VLQ flag is marked as helpful, unlike the spam/offensive flags where it is applied immediately and then removed if a moderator dismisses the flag as disputed/declined.

Comment: @Behaviour [here's a pretty thorough explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215328/165773) given by Shog9 over at MSE. For a fuller story, refer [SE change log (aka "Recent feature changes...")](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773), entries dated 2013-08-05, 2012-01-20, 2011-04-14

Comment: Another idea: increase the vote capacity based on how often the capacity was reached. Every 50 (or something like that) days gives you an additional vote.

Comment: @GertArnold are you aware that SE team seeks input on something like that: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773) Answers over there suggest adding weight, increasing limit of close votes etc

Comment: @ArtjomB. see above ^^^ "SE team seeks input on something like that..."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables You're definitely not the only person hitting the limits..!. Let me just repeat what you said- I freely admit -- I cast more downvotes than upvotes anymore, because I see so many bad questions. Maybe I'm just on here too much, maybe I'm overly-critical, maybe I'm jaded, or, as I am inclined to believe, there really are that many more bad questions on the site. Maybe it's a combination of all three, who knows.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the explanation of VLQ->DV connection. Unfortunately, the recent change to VLQ rules (it's not available for questions under review) limits  the applicability of this feature.

Comment: @Behaviour good catch. I also noticed that and it made me somewhat sad... for a few hours, until I figured that [there are benefits besides drawbacks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244717/disputed-flags-and-triage/244736#comment800110_244736 "'Forcing flaggers to use (and learn about!) close flags...'") and decided that I can live without the VLQ option when a question is already in the close / triage queue

Comment: If we look at the effects that downvoting a bad question has, we can clearly see that downvoting is just another form of punishment (for writing a bad question, or in some cases, disagreeing with what it says). To increase votes, it would be more beneficial to you, and the community, if instead you simply leave a comment describing what you feel ie wrong with the question or answer and how it can be improved (e.g. providing more details, links, formatting, etc) - or edit the question yourself if you think you can improve it.

Comment: @jay_t55: There are other questions about wanting to remove all downvoting as unfriendly. You'll get the proper response there.

Answer (score 42):

Giving everyone the same number of votes means that everyone has an equal say in how the site is being moderated.

Many posts are in a "grey area", and both keeping them and closing or deleting them are valid options; voting isn't necessarily objective. This is why posts are moderated by humans and not an algorithm, and why you need multiple people to close or delete a post.

Should we give more votes to (very) active users? I don't necessarily see *why*; you may have run out of close votes, but the next person hasn't, and she would use hers to cast the vote, or maybe not; that's *her* decision, making it her decision, means that she *also* has her say in how the site is moderated.

This keeps moderating a *community effort*, where everyone contributes his or her little opinion a little bit; just like voting for your parliament or congress is a community effort, where everyone contributes a little bit of opinion.

Comment: Everyone already does have the same number of votes one can cast. It's exactly one per item. As such that is already a guarantee that everyone can partake democratically. There's no one hindering the "next person" from casting a vote whether you have reached your daily limit or not. I actually think the daily limit on votes *reduces* democracy: You're suddenly not allowed to vote one one specific item while others - who didn't read the hundreds of items you've had today - still can and do.

Comment: If anything we should value the opinions of heavy users more, not less. I'm happy if we value it the same, i believe it's the best solution so that power users don't get too much power ;-)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit If you narrowly look at it on a question-basis, then you're right. But if you look at it *sitewide*, then not. Then it just becomes a question of who had the most spare time, or is the most bored at work, and thus has the time to look at (& vote at) the "hundreds of items" every day....

Comment: Yes of course. But how is that problematic? You still get only 1 vote per item and you can easily be "overpowered" by the thousands of other users of the site. If they don't care and don't vote - that's their right too. Ok i can see that it could be problematic with close votes. But should that problem not be solved by people being able to "not close" vote? So that (nearly) everyone, too, has a say in whether to close or not?

Comment: `or is the most bored at work` -> If you only do it because of that, it worries me. I do it at home in my leisure time rather than at work, because I like it! What is the problem?

Comment: @lpapp You have never been in a job where there are days that there is very little or nothing to do? At my previous job, for example, there were those days (for the silliest of reasons, but that's a whole story not suitable here).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: luckily not, no, I nearly always have far too much on my plate, and even then, my idea would be to increase productivity at the company rather than filling up the paid time with non-productive SO contribution for my company.

Answer (score 20):

I rarely hit this limit, but when I do, it enrages me, and I support increasing it.

I personally care rather little about downvoting crap questions, but I hit the limit in a different scenario. Sometimes, I'll come across an interesting, subtle, popular question with *lots* of answers and read them all, voting as I go. As I write this answer, I'm doing so for [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

That question has 27 answers, and I've already cast some votes today. I'll probably want to vote one way or another on 20 or so of the answers, and it's going to take me over my limit. The result is that I'll feel obligated to favourite the question and come back tomorrow, because it just doesn't sit well with me to have upvoted or downvoted some answers to a question while letting even better/worse ones go without votes because I hadn't reached them yet. People doing what I do with these questions *ought* to be the mechanism by which clever, insightful, comprehensive, or otherwise unusually useful gems of answers posted late on popular questions are given the chance to the rise to the top of the list. Instead, this restriction damns those answers to obscurity unless people like me spread our voting over multiple days. Argh!

This annoys me, wastes my time, restricts my ability to contribute to the site, and seems pointless. What purpose is this limit *meant* to serve, anyway?

Comment: Does that really mean you want to have a higher limit, or rather a cap on how many markers voting on *all* answers on a question will use up?

Comment: The latter would solve *my* problem entirely adequately, @Deduplicator, and I'd welcome it. That said, for reasons not touched on in this answer I'd *still* support raising the vote limit. I feel for the frustrated OP of this question who finds themself blocked from one means of contributing to the site for the rest of the day because they've already contributed too much. What's the point of that? It seems to be a straightforwardly bad thing, both because we're stopping them doing things that are *useful* and because we're forcing them to waste time and mental effort "conserving" their votes.

Answer (score 11):

Although your question is clearly about getting more votes, you seem to tell that you have a problem that could be solved (by Stack Exchange) without changing the quota.

> I'll freely admit -- I cast more downvotes than upvotes anymore, because I see so many bad questions.

**The fact may be that downvote deserving questions get too much attention (from you and from the users in general). By reducing this attention, you could have "votes offered", the votes you don't spend downvoting because of a reduced need to do it.**

How can SO reduce attention spent at questions not deserving it? That's a question with maybe no unique answer.

---

Here is a way, requiring adjustments, that seems interesting to me:

- Provide a way, granted for >= 750 rep users, to flag questions with a suspensive effect, when the question author is less than 100 rep.
- If this feature is used, the question is temporarily treated as one "hidden" from usual views and non specific resources.
- The "flag" has its usual effects, and a review of the flag (when done) will either remove the "attention removal" effect or permit the closing of the question.
- When a question author would be affected by this measure, he would be notified. The notification would automatically remind him the reasons of the flag, quotes of SO principles, and links to relevant SO resources.
- By receiving this notification, the question author would be given the options of either agreeing with the flag, ask for a removal of the suspensive effects, or editing the question to cope with the reasons causing the flag.

So, once the question author knows about the visibility suspension of his question, he is able to first learn better how SO works and then take action to cancel the visibility suspension, if he still thinks than his question deserve visibility. Only his lack of action (combined with no quick moderator review) would cause the visibility reduction to last a long time.

To my mind, this approach would have the following benefits:

- Less attention would be given to a good rate of low quality questions.
- This would then cost more downvotes in general.
- People willing to read and answer would be more happy, and more efficient.
- Because the new user would learn more quickly from his mistakes on SO, it will be less frustrating from him too.

However it has points requiring attention to be implemented the best way:

- People able to flag should be enough "aware" of the possibility of doing it. Currently, a downvote may be too much intuitive compared to flagging.
- Flagging quota would diminish more quickly. A good change would be to refill the quota if either the author or a moderator agrees with the flag.

Remember it's just a way, among others, for reducing visibility of low quality questions. Lot of others people could have their opinions on how to do it if they think about it. **The main point of this answer remains that by reducing the visibility of low quality questions, users would earn the extra votes they didn't need to waste in the first place.**

Comment: consider opening the answer with TL;DR similar to one you end with. Something like, **"For SE team, there are two options to address the issue you raise. First is to give active users more votes down. Second is to get better of hiding downvote-worthy garbage from readers."**

Comment: @gnat: interesting way to say it more efficiently ;)