# What's the point of limiting votes per day?

Tags: discussion

Why am I limited to 40 votes per day, even as my reputation goes up? Shouldn't medium-rep users be trusted as non-bots?

Comment: For the same reason the rep cap exists: To limit the amount of influence a single user can have by promoting quality over quantity. If you just go throwing your votes around all willynilly, you're not going to have votes available when you really want/need them.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254453/increase-max-daily-votes and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280051/i-would-like-to-have-more-than-3010-votes-per-day

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/386/ … but limit may give you chance to have life outside of SO :)

Comment: The whole point of votes is to distinguish high-quality posts from low-quality posts. Even just for questions, it's *very* easy to run into huge numbers of closeworthy low-quality ones, even when not looking for them, and voting on them sends an important message to the poster and to other viewers about what sort of content is suited and useful for the site. On particularly active days, it's not hard to use up all votes in a few hours, at least for one who watches posts as they come in, while voting conscientiously.

Comment: IIRC, my record was 5 hours to use up all my close/delete votes, (homework Sunday).

Comment: @MartinJames horror! What did you do with the remaining 19 hours of that Sunday? Angry yelling at your screen?

Answer (score 5):

Quite naturally you don't want single user to have too much impact. Some users upvote good questions (of a great quality and content), they're voting quite rarely. By allowing users for unlimited voting they will be overwhelmed (more than they're now) by users giving voted like candies.